# Positioning a subview when called from an UITableviewControllers in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, subview

I have used in my `UITableviewController`:

```
self.view.superview?.addSubview(PopUpControls)
```

It pops-up fine but not in the right position.
How do you set the position for a subview?

Comment: Your view has a `frame` property that accepts a `CGRect`, you can use this or you can use interface builder.

Answer (score 3):

You probably just need to change the origin after you add the view as a sub-view:

```
// Set the Y (up, down) position of the view.
PopUpControls.frame.origin.y = <CGFLOAT>
// Set the X (left, right) position of the view
PopUpControls.frame.origin.x = <CGFLOAT>
```

#### Edit:

To add constraints to a view, you do it like this:

```
// 1
if let superView = self.view.superview {

    // 2
    superView.addSubview(PopUpControls)

    // 3
    PopUpControls.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

    // 4
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([

            // 5
            NSLayoutConstraint(item: PopUpControls, attribute: .top, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: superView, attribute: .top, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 15),

            // 6
            NSLayoutConstraint(item: PopUpControls, attribute: .left, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: superView, attribute: .left, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 5),

            // 7
            PopUpControls.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 15),

            //8
            PopUpControls.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 10)
        ])
}
```

Here is what I am doing:

1. Making sure the controller's view has a super view (Question specific.).
2. Adding the view to the super view.
3. Setting the view so we don't have any auto-generated constraints. This could cause problems.
4. Activating any constraints in the array passed into the method.
5. Creating a constraint between the view (PopUpControls) and the super view. It is connected to the top of each of the elements with a distance of 15 points.
6. Doing the same as #5, just the left of each element instead of the top.
7. Setting the elements height to 15 points.
8. Setting the elements width to 10 points.

This should be done in the `viewDidLayoutSubviews` method of the controller.

Comment: That worked perfectly - the pop-up now "floats" exactly where I want it. 
For other newbies <CGFLOAT> is just a number.
I now need to find a way to add constraints so that the view moves when I change orientation. 
Thanks

Comment: A small edition to the solution:
    PopUpControls.frame.size.width = 280
   PopUpControls.frame.size.height = 330
Looking for ways of setting constraints

Comment: @Jeremy I updated my answer to include some stuff on constraints. Hope it helps you out.

Comment: The constraint solution looks brilliant - thanks - just stuck on declaring   tempHighIcon.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false gives unresolved identifier

Comment: @Jeremy Sorry. I forgot to fix the view name when I pasted the code into the answer :^). I fixed it.

Comment: I am using Storyboards and it makes quite a difference where  you place the PopUpControls view.  I have found placing it outside the Table View works best.
Not sure if I am allowed to ask this on this site - but - do you do any contract work?

Comment: @Jeremy Yes, I am willing to do contract work. This is off topic ;^), so if you want to continue on this topic you can shoot me an e-mail at caleb.kleveter at gmail dot com

Answer (score 0):

```
self.view.superview?.addSubview
```

Something has gone wrong if you ever need to do this.

The common way to send messages back up the chain is to use delegation.

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/Delegation.html

Basically you define a protocol that one object has a reference to and the other object implements. That way you can send messages from the first object to the second. A child view should never be directly responsible for adding views directly to it's superview.

For the actual problem you have with setting the position, it depends on if you are using autolayout or not. If you are not them you simply need to set the x and y components of the view PopUpControls frame. If you are using autolayout then you will need to define it's constraints.

Comment: I am afraid as a Newbie I am finding some documentation hard to understand.

Comment: @Jeremy Here is an example of a delegate in swift http://stackoverflow.com/a/24925505/385816